# Were ancient astronomers (Babylonians, Egyptians or Greeks) aware of the solar analemma?

Tags: astronomy, archaeoastronomy

Is there any proof or even just indication that they did: I can't find anything online and was hoping for some help.

Comment: *Some* sort of "awareness", as required in construction analemmatic sundials, can be traced as far as the Bronze Age, see [Vodolazhskaya](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.07502). There is some educated speculation that analemmatic diagrams were used by ancient Greeks to carve conic sundials from the time of Conon, see [Rinner](https://edition-topoi.org/article/1317-ancient-greek-sundials-and-the-theory-of-conic-sections-reconsidered/).

Comment: But the earliest known source that draws the solar analemma explicitly is Vitruvius c. 30 BC, see [Kittler-Darula, Analemma, the Ancient Sketch of Fictitious Sunpath Geometry](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00038628.2004.9697037):"*Vitruvius summarised already around the year 30 BC the rough approximations of gnomon shades for different towns. In Book 9, Chapter 7, Vitruvius explained how to draw the so-called analemma commonly used to design sundials*". The name "analemma" was used in the early 1st century AD by Diodorus of Alexandria.

Comment: Thank you very much!